# How to turn off "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" in facebook app

Tags: facebook, oauth, sitecore, sitecore-social-connected

Is there any way to turn off the option `Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs` in a Facebook app? It seems that as of March 2018 this property automatically is turned on and is greyed out so cannot be disabled. Facebook seems to disallow authentication unless the exact URL is mentioned in `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs`. This is a problem because the Sitecore Social Connected module seems to pass in a different state parameter in the query string each time you log in. I have tested using the `Redirect URI Validator` in the Facebook app and this confirms that the redirect must be exactly as per `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs`.

Comment: No there is no way to turn it off

Comment: @WizKid in that case, is there any way to handle the situation of the Sitecore Social Connected module generating a URL with a different query string each time?

Comment: Only to change it to not generate a unique string every time I believe

Comment: The only thing that does not fall under that restriction, is the `state` parameter - so if you need to transport any individual information with a login dialog call, you can put it in there. Since this value also takes care of CSRF protection, if you have to transport a static or easily guessable value, I would recommend that you still combine it with a random one. (Could be for example simply the JSON string containing `[your value, random value]` or something like that.)

Comment: @CBroe even when I add to "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"  e.g. `http://example.com/my-redirect.ashx?type=access&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location&type=web_server&state={state-param}` the Redirect URI Validator will give an error for `http://example.com/my-redirect.ashx?type=access&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location&type=web_server&state=123456`. Not sure if I should be specifying some sort of wildcard for the state parameter value?

Comment: The value the `redirect_uri` parameter has in your actual login dialog call needs to be specified in this field. (That should not contain any `state` to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand you. After clicking our login with facebook button, the user is taken to a page such as: `https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://example.com/my-redirect.ashx?type=access&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location&type=web_server&state=a463df5c-3a76-4413-b118-58e70e72d007`

Comment: So, the value of your redirect_uri parameter is `http://example.com/my-redirect.ashx?type=access` ... the rest are parameters of the login dialog.

Comment: I already find out how it is. Please see this reference link for the solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: @RalphOlazo that article is a generic tutorial about facebook/social authentication. It doesn't mention anything about strict mode for redirect URIs related to Facebook.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any way to turn off the option `Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs` in a Facebook app?

## NO

Due to the security changes made to Facebook, it's no longer possible to turn off this setting.

---

Regarding specifics of Sitecore and the Social Connected module, I found from @CBroe's comments that the `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` now needs to contain a query string parameter as follows:

```
http://example.com/layouts/Social/Connector/SocialLogin.ashx?type=access
```

previously I just had

```
http://example.com/layouts/Social/Connector/SocialLogin.ashx
```

If you are using HTTPS, you will need to enter the URI with the port number as well i.e.

```
https://example.com:443/layouts/Social/Connector/SocialLogin.ashx?type=access
```

This last point is not related to the recent Facebook app changes.

Answer (score 1):

Same experience, I could not turn it off. What eventually worked for me was

I have a link on my site that starts the login process:

```
https://www.example.com/users/auth/facebook
```

Following this causes my rails app to redirect to

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=123456
```

Facebook replies with

```
https://www.example.com/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=abcverylongcodexyz
```

Therefor the URI that needs to be whitelisted is simply "https://www.example.com/users/auth/facebook/callback", without the code part.

FWIW, when I moved my site from http to https I needed to update my config/initializers/devise.rb to include

```
config.omniauth :facebook, '1234', '34567', :scope => 'email', :callback_url => 'https://www.example.com/users/auth/facebook/callback'
```

as it was still using the http: protocol in the callback url, and you can't whitelist any URI in that protocol under the current guidelines.